# Is there an equivalent for getch() in Scala?

Tags: c, scala

I'm looking for a function in Scala that has similar functionality to getch. While using the console, I'd like to have my program display information based on what characters the user inputs (for example, if I was displaying a text, hitting n would show the next page, and p the previous). Right now I'm using readLine or readChar, but they require the user to hit Enter after each input, a bit annoying. Plus, in Eclipse plug-in's interpreter, the input character is shown, although I guess that might be unavoidable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`scala.Console.readChar`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Console%24), aliased in in current incarnations of Scala as [`Predef.getChar`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24) is the most direct way.

```
scala> readChar
res0: Char = !
```

*UPDATE*

This time without the pesky `Enter`:

```
scala> Console.in.read.toChar
res0: Char = !
```

Comment: I tried it also (scala 2.9.0.1 and java 1.6.0_24), but it requires me to press **Enter**

Comment: I'll mark this as being the answer, since it's a Scala solution, although this is equivalent to Easy Angel's response.

Answer (score 3):

Use StdIn lib:

```
    StdIn.readChar()
```

Comment: In sclala 2.11, this requires that one press Enter but it discards the Enter, which is handy.

Comment: This is nice, but if you just press enter, you get an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Java's [Console](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) that was added in **1.6**. Here is REPL session:

```
scala> val r  = System.console().reader()
r: java.io.Reader = java.io.Console$LineReader@1d97efc

scala> r.read.toChar
res8: Char = t
```

*during repl session I pressed **t** key after executing second expression*

`reed` method does not require **Enter** and returns as soon as you press key.

Comment: Ah, I should've imagined there was a Java solution to this. It worked, cheers.